# Can the FragmentManager set content within a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I currently have `Fragments` which are both placed into normal layouts and shown as `DialogFragments`. Each Fragment has its own actions, most of which consist of replacing the current layout with another fragment.

So what I would like to know is: can the `FragmentManager` set the layout content within the DialogFragment `Window`? I don't like the idea of making the Fragments check whether they are a DialogFragment or not in order to determine what the next Fragment state should be.

Answer (score 0):

> can the FragmentManager set the layout content within the
>   DialogFragment Window?

No, the `FragmentManager` is responsible for getting a reference/ working with the fragments. The fragments themselves should be responsible for their layouts.

> I don't like the idea of making the Fragments check whether they are a
>   DialogFragment or not in order to determine what the next Fragment
>   state should be.

You could pass a boolean value to any new instances of your fragments through a `Bundle` so the fragments will know from the start the state it's in.

Comment: That is more or less what I decided on doing. I placed a boolean in a fragment superclass to identify the dialog states. The fragment which they are nested in then checks the state of the fragment to decide whether or not the next fragment should be displayed as a `DialogFragment` or within a layout.